# cURL not submitting but no error messages

Tags: php, curl

This is my first cURL function. I followed the code on an online tutorial and came up with this:

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.example.com");
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "apiKey=var1&message=var2&to=var3&from=var4");

    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

The POST variables are not being sent, however I'm not getting any error messages in my PHP log either.

Comment: What is your Php and curl version ? It can be due to your Curl version. Try to change it.

Comment: I'm using version 7 - ah this might make sense then, do I need to install something for Curl to work?

Comment: Try to install an another version of curl

Comment: The curl installation all seems fine :(

Comment: Ahhh!!! Solved it, it was because it was a HTTPS address, turns out the 3rd party also accept request to HTTP so just did that and problem solved :)

Comment: Is your target URL protocol https, as you wrote in your code snippet? Because you might have SSL-generated problems.

Answer (score 0):

For cURL-related errors, use curl_error() to get error messages:
Example from [php.net](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php):

```
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
```